# How to execute HTTP sampler by only one thread at a time in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My application is not allowing to execute one of the HTTP sampler by multiple threads at a time and throwing "RECORD_LOCKED" exception. So please suggest how to create synchronized sampler(should be execute only one thread at a time ) to solve this issue.

Assume below are my samplers in Thread group and I want to run this thread group with 10 threads. But the 2nd HTTP sampler should be executed by only one thread group at a time. After login completion(2nd sampler) of one thread then only another thread should execute that sampler.

- Thread Group 1

  1. Login page HTTP Sampler
  2. Enter UserName / Password and click on Login HTTP Sampler
  3. Home Page View HTTP Sampler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Lock the specific Sampler from other threads use the controller:

Right click the HTTP Sampler-> Insert Parent -> Logic Controller -> [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

> Critical Section Controller ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread